# Updating MySql table when clicking a button based on content from the table (but not when refreshing the page)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm randomly loading a string from a database table which is used to load a YouTube video. When the user clicks a button, I want a value related to the loaded video to be updated in the database.

Previously I had: `$uv = $mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET x = x + 1 WHERE embedcode = '" . $row[embedcode]. "';");` and `<a href="<?php echo $uv ?>">test</a>`

This works but is triggered when the page loads as opposed to just when the button is clicked. I don't have to use an anchor tag, I just assumed that doing so would mean that only when clicking on the link would the table be updated, but apparently not.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

it allows for values to be sent without refresh using javascript and xml